# How to retrieve a value from dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have this function that fetch users from `FireBase` and convert them in `Dictionary`:

```
 let leaderBoardDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("scores1").queryOrderedByValue().queryLimited(toLast: 5)
        leaderBoardDB.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("scores scores", snapshot)

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                for playa in dictionary {
                    let player = Player()

                    print("plaaaaayyyyyaaaaa", playa)
                    print("plaaaaayyyyyaaaaa key", playa.key)
                    print("plaaaaayyyyyaaaaa.value", playa.value)
                        player.id = playa.key
                    print(playa.key["name"])

                }
            }   
          }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

and I get this result:

> plaaaaayyyyyaaaaa ("inovoID", {
>        name = Tatiana;
>        points = 6; })  plaaaaayyyyyaaaaa key inovoID  plaaaaayyyyyaaaaa.value {
>        name = Tatiana;
>       points = 6; } aaaa i id Optional("inovoID")

the problem is that i can't obtain the name and the points of the user. when i try it with:

```
print(playa.key["name"])
```

it gaves me this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'

can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: playa.objectForKey("name") it should work

Comment: it doesn't. it says: **Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'objectForKey'**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your JSON is

```
"inovoID" : { "name" : "Tatiana", "points" : 6 }
```

- `playa.key` is `"inovoID"`
- `playa.value` is `{ "name" : "Tatiana", "points" : 6 }`

The **key** is `String` and cannot be subscripted. That's what the error says.

You need to subscribe the **value** and safely cast the type to help the compiler.

```
if let person = playa.value as? [String:Any] {
   print(person["name"] as! String)
}
```

Comment: @vadian can i get `print(person[0] as! String)` by just refering the index?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper No, you can't, only an array is index based, a dictionary is always key based.

Comment: @vadian thanx, is there any alternate so i can store index based values from json file?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper You have to transform your data into an array compatible form.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for:

`player.name = dictionary["name"] as? String`

You don't need to iterate through the dictionary to access it's values. If you're looking for the value of a key, just get it.

Comment: i'm iterating because i want to add the player to an Array of players and then retrieve the name and the score.

Comment: It looks like the dictionary over which you're iterating is a JSON object. You need to convert the value of the item into a Dictionary as well

Comment: @PeejWeej can i get `print(person[0] as! String)` by just refering the index?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper If you care about indexes, use an `Array` not a `Dictionary`