# How can I get strings from array object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new in IOS,
I get this response from backend

```
Optional([["contact_name": phone, "verified": <null>, "id": 22033, "entity_id": 1111, "verification_data": <null>, "entity": Recruiter, "view_scope": <null>, "contact_value": 0987654321]])
```

I need "contact_value" string from object.How can I get?

Comment: It's not an array, it's a dictionary.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no, it's an array of dictionaries, note double square brackets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067025/how-to-retrieve-a-value-from-dictionary-in-swift-3

Comment: @mag_zbc, you're right. I missed that, still to get the value OP needs to access the dictionary finally.

Comment: I think what OP should do regardless is to read about collections in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html). This is an excellent source if you're new to Swift (and also more experienced) to learn the basics of the language. It's also available as an iBook. Much recommended

Comment: dictonary denoted by this { }

Comment: @RealmOfFire Did you read some basics in Swift language?  see here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

Comment: @Mani sorry i talk about objective cand thnx for correcting me

Comment: @YogeshNikam, contact_value looks like a phone number to me so I would typecast it to a String (as? String) rather than an int to not loose the starting 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let array: [[String: Any]] = [["contact_name": "John", "verified": true, "id": 22033, "entity_id": 1111, "verification_data": "", "entity": "Recruiter", "view_scope": "", "contact_value": 0987654321]]

for item in array {
    let contactName = item["contact_name"] as? String
    print(contactName ?? 0)
}
```

This is just a basic for/loop to extract the data, but there are a lot of better ways to accomplish this stuff depending on how your code is implemented.

Comment: @mag_zbc I was just trying to show a simple for/loop and grabing the data. I updated the array to complile

Comment: Could you fix your answer so it reads the right key. Right now you're typecasting a String value to an Int.

Comment: Thank You so much

Answer (score 3):

Instead of normal for-loop, [try map concept](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map). **Note:** This is tested code.

```
let arrayOfDict: [[String: Any]] = [["contact_name": "phone", "verified": "", "id": 22033, "entity_id": 1111, "verification_data": "", "entity": "Recruiter", "view_scope": "", "contact_value": 0987654321]]

let arraOfCtcName : [Int] = arrayOfDict.map({ (element) in
            let value = element["contact_value"]
            return (value != nil && value is Int) ? value as! Int : 0
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could as well go a little more functional, if all you want is contact_value,

```
let contactValues = a.flatMap { $0 }?
    .map { $0["contact_value"] ?? 0 } as? [Int]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayOfDict: [[[String: Any]] = ["contact_name": "phone", "verified": <null value>, "id": 22033, "entity_id": 1111, "verification_data": <null value>, "entity": "Recruiter", "view_scope": <null value>, "contact_value": 0987654321], ....]

var arrayContact = [Any]()

for dict in arrayOfDict {

  if let contactValue = dict["contact_value"] as? String { //as String
    arrayContact.append(contactValue)
  } else if let contactValue = dict["contact_value"] as? Int { //as Int
    arrayContact.append(contactValue)
  }
}

print(arrayContact)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array: [[String: Any]] = [["contact_name": "John", "verified": true, "id": 22033, "entity_id": 1111, "verification_data": "", "entity": "Recruiter", "view_scope": "", "contact_value": 0987654321]]

print(array)

for item in array {
    if item["contact_value"] != nil {
        let contact_value = String(describing: item["contact_value"])
        print(contact_value)
        break
    }
}
```